# Can't authentic Livepatch on Mac's Parallels

Tags: login, password, canonical-livepatch, parallels

I just installed the Parallels app for Mac OS. I tried to install the latest Ubuntu which worked successfully. In the process, I created a password for logging into Ubuntu and a password for Ubuntu One. In the set up I came across something called Livepatch, which I tried to complete. However, after logging into the Ubuntu One, I get a window saying Authentication Required...The password you use to log in to your computer no longer matches that of your login keyring. I tried using the password to get into Ubuntu along with the Ubuntu One password, but neither work. Am I missing something here? Thank you for your time.

Edit: So apparently this is an [old issue](https://forum.parallels.com/threads/centos-fedora-mint-linux-login-keyring-issue-the-password-you-use-to-login-to-your-computer.343215/). It seems to be regarding the Ubuntu keyring, which in an older version 18.04 had the default password of 'parallels'. I tried it again in 20.04, and it seems to not be working. I am still not sure about a workaround.

Comment: See this link: https://blog.roberthallam.org/2010/07/current-password-does-not-match-keyring-fix/ It's almost annoying how simple the fix is given the amount of time I have spent trying to resolve it. It is as simple as "Change Password" - Put your "currrent" one in the old, and then again in the new again twice and ... Done.

Answer (score 1):

Update: For this issue on Ubuntu 20.04 with Parallels Desktop, the default password of 'parallels' no longer works. Instead, run this command to reset your keyring password:

```
rm ~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring
```